# In PostgreSQL , can certificate authentication and basic authentication(username/password authentication) co-exist at one time?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11, postgresql-12

Can we configure both Basic authentication and Certificate authentication for PostgreSQL simultaneously for the same IP address of client.
I think no , because they are 2 different authentication mechanisms and cannot co-exist at same time... because if we configure for certificate authentication , then it cannot use username password for authentication , but have to use only certificates for authentication.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried myself.
In pg_hba.conf file, we can set MD5 authentication for 1 set of IP address and cert for another IP address range.
So 1 Postgres server can address 2 different authentication for 2 different IP address

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can specify [`clientcert`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ssl-tcp.html) in conjunction with any of the authentication methods.  so `md5  clientcert=verify-full` would require both a cert and a password.

verify-full was only introduced in v12.  Prior to that, you could only make it check that the cert was validly signed, not that the CN on the cert matched the username being claimed.

Comment: In PostgreSQL ,  SSL can be configured at 2 places  (1) for the connection  (2) Authentication. My question is on this Certificate Authentication and not at connection level.  PostgreSQL support multiple authentication methods ..Out of them we have basic authentication , that is username/pwd authentication & Certificate authentication is also an option . This link talks about certificate authentication - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/auth-cert.html .So my question is can we have both certificate authentication and basic authentication configured at the same time. i think no.Please clarify

Comment: I provided a direct answer to your question, yes you can have both, and demonstrated how.  What more clarification is needed?

Comment: i went through the link you gave on clientcert . It talks about securing the connection with SSL in addition to usrname and password , (which is the (1) point that i referred in my comment earlier ).  So at any given time, i think, we cannot have both certificate authentication and username/password authentication... since in certifcate authentication we need not necessarily give username and password

Answer (score 0):

Basic Auth and SSL can be achieved with postgres groups and roles. Follow below steps-

**Create new group**

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "CREATE GROUP testcertificateusers";
```

**Alter group to add new users/CN/roles-**

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "ALTER GROUP testcertificateusers ADD USER user";
```

**To see members of group**

```
psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "SELECT * FROM pg_roles";

psql -U postgres -d postgres -c "SELECT * FROM pg_auth_members";
#(oid column from above query will be shown as a members of the group)
```

**Update pg_hba.conf file**

**Add hostssl line before ipv4 host connection**

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

hostssl all +testcertificateusers 0.0.0.0/0  cert clientcert=1

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
```