# PostgreSQL: Successful Authentication with Wrong Password XD : Can I use md5 AND `clientcert=verify-full` simultaneously?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql database server running inside a docker container. The connection being attempted uses a client certificate AND a password. But it seems that, when using a `sslmode='verify-full'` in the connection string and `cert clientcert=verify-full` in `pg_hba.conf`, the password is ignored. So, my question is: can I use `md5|scram-sha-256` AND `clientcert='verify-full'` at the same time?

I looked into the following SO question: [In PostgreSQL , can certificate authentication and basic authentication(username/password authentication) co-exist at one time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64065247/in-postgresql-can-certificate-authentication-and-basic-authenticationusername)

But, the answers are mixed and I cannot find a definitive answer.

I also tried using `md5 clientcert=verify-full` in `pg_hba.conf` but it seemed that the client certificate was ignored. So, I'm thinking that I can only choose one or the other, but I'm not sure.

If you can, provide a reference from an official source.

Comment: Did you restart the server after making the change?

Answer (score 0):

The top answer seems quite clear to me and the docs are still the best place to see the structure of pg_hba.conf

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

I suspect where you tried two methods the second one is being treated as options for the first method. Unrecognised options might well be ignored.